# How to detect pid that generates outbound traffic on Solaris?

Tags: networking, solaris, firewall, network-monitoring

Is there a firewall of some sort on Solaris that will let me define a filter, for instance outbound traffic to a certain range of ip adresses and port, but instead of blocking the traffic I want to log the process id and user?

Answer (score 0):

I believe dtrace can extract that information.  Check some of the scripts in here such as tcptop:

http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit